# How to use Google Analytics to track referrer on conversion

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, web-statistics

My company uses GA for a landing site we have. When a user sends us an email from the site, GA counts this as a conversion. However, the referrer is our own site so we never know where they came from. The referrer information gets lost once they arrive at the "Send us an inquiry" page.

How can we get this information?

Thank you.

Comment: GA tracks  the referrer by default. If that does not work for you then something is wrong with your setup (first of all your own domain should be in the properties referral exclusion list to avoi self-referrals). You should check if at some point on the way to the "Send inquiry" page the GA session is interrupted and the original tracking source is reset.

Comment: Okay, I'll check the referral exclusion list as a start. Thanks.